# SunCertPathBuilderException => Maven JAXB2 generation with certificate

Tags: java, wsdl, maven-3, jaxb2, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I'm using maven-jaxb2, to generate classes to make calls to a webservice.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>https://my-secured-webservice.com/file?wsdl</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
        <generateDirectory>src\main\java</generateDirectory>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The wsdl needs a certificate which is correctly installed on my machine. I can access the wsdl with my browser.

I've added 2 properties with the properties-maven-plugin

```
<property>
    <name>javax.net.ssl.keyStore</name>
    <value>/path/to/JKS/file.jks</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword</name>
    <value>my-super-secret-password</value>
</property>
```

I've created my jks file by:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass my-super-secret-password -destkeystore /path/to/JKS/file.jks -srckeystore /path/to/file.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
```

When the I'm triggering mvn:generate-sources, I've got following error popping up:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; IOException thrown when processing "https://my-secured-webservice.com/file?wsdl". Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry.. I fixed this on my own:

I've picked the certificate from de wsdl location. (I've used chrome to download the .crt file)

Then:

```
sudo keytool -importcert -file /path/to/downloaded/certificate.crt -alias myalias -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

So I imported the certificate to my cacerts..